# Rendering to a single Bitmap object from multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, graphics, bitmap, rendering

What im doing is rendering a number of bitmaps to a single bitmap. There could be hundreds of images and the bitmap being rendered to could be over 1000x1000 pixels.

Im hoping to speed up this process by using multiple threads but since the Bitmap object is not thread-safe it cant be rendered to directly concurrently. What im thinking is to split the large bitmap into sections per cpu, render them separately then join them back together at the end. I haven't done this yet incase you guys/girls have any better suggestions.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use LockBits and work on individual sections of the image.

For an example of how this is done you can look at the Paint.Net source code, especially the [BackgroundEffectsRenderer](http://code.google.com/p/paint-mono/source/browse/trunk/src/Effects/BackgroundEffectRenderer.cs) (yes that is a link to the mono branch, but the Paint.Net main code seems to be only available in zip files).

Answer (score 1):

Lee, if you're going to use the Image GDI+ object, you may just end up doing all the work twice. The sections that you generate in multiple threads will need to be reassembled at the end of your divide and conquer approach and wouldn't that defeat the purpose of dividing in the first place?

This issue might only be overcome if you're doing something rather complex in each of the bitmap sections that would be much more processing time than simply redrawing the image subparts onto the large bitmap without going to all that trouble.

Hope that helps. What kind of image rendering are you planning out?

Comment: yeah I thought that just after I posted, there's nothing extra going on apart from drawing n Bitmaps to one large one, nearly all the time spent is in the DrawImage method. Need a new idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could have each thread write to a byte array, then when they are all finished, use a single thread to create a bitmap object from the byte arrays. If all other processing has been done before hand, that should be pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar and in my case I had each thread lock x (depended on the size of the image and the number of threads) many rows of bits in the image, and do their writing to those bits such that no threads ever overlapped their writes.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to render all the small bitmaps onto an *ersatz* bitmap, which would just be a two-dimensional `int` array (which is kind of all a `Bitmap` really is anyway).  Once all the small bitmaps are combined in the big array, you do a one-time copy from the big array into a real `Bitmap` of the same dimensions.

I use this approach (not including the multi-threaded aspect) all the time for complex graphics on Windows Mobile devices, since the memory available for creating "real" GDI+ Bitmaps is severely limited.

You could also just use a `Bitmap` as you originally intended.  `Bitmap` is not guaranteed to be thread-safe, but I'm not sure that would be a problem as long as you could assure that no two threads are ever overwriting the same portion of the bitmap.  I'd give it a try, at least.

**Update:**  I just re-read your question, and I realized that you're probably not going to see much (if any) improvement in the overall speed of these operations by making them multi-threaded.  It's the classic nine-women-can't-make-a-baby-in-one-month problem.