# Copy one Bitmap onto a larger Bitmap using without using Graphics.DrawImage

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, bitmap, unmanaged

This is a follow up from [Rendering to a single Bitmap object from multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648975/rendering-to-a-single-bitmap-object-from-multiple-threads)

What im trying to achieve is to take a bitmap of say 50x50 pixels and draw it onto a larger bitmap(100x100 pixels) at any point on the larger image, using the bitmaps LockBits function or any other but NOT graphics.DrawImage. My reasons for not wanting to use DrawImage is stated in the other thread.

I have managed to get something by using Marshal.Copy from the source BitmapData to the dest BitmapData but its creating a tiled, stretched image horizontally.

Comment: A follow up? I't just the same question over again.

Comment: Its a more focused question and as far i'm getting more focused answers.

Answer (score 4):

You could manipulate the image in memory without relying on any system calls. If you dig into the underlying format of a .BMP file you could build your own Device Independant Bitmap class that truly "understands" the low level format of a .BMP.

For example a 8 bit per pixel image is essentially a 2 dimensional array of bytes (each byte is 1 pixel) plus a simple color table. Roughly speaking (and this is very very rough):

```
byte[,] bColors = new byte[3,256]; // 256 RGB colors
byte[,] bImage = new byte[25,50]; // 25 x 50 pixels
```

The trick is (as always) getting a hold of the raw pixel data, doing the processing, and then updating the raw pixel data with your changes.

In the past I've approached this by converting a GDI HBITMAP into a 24bpp DIB, doing my funky image processing on the raw pixels (3 bytes per pixels makes this easier), then converting the DIB back into a HBITMAP. This was all using just classic GDI (pre GDI+ even, let alone C#).

Using that approach you could design a control structure to allow multiple writers to different sections of your much bigger image.

However... the lowlevel BitBlt GDI calls are likely to be way more efficient that anything you can do. If I were you I'd make certain that just doing 50 or 100 bitblt's in a row would be too slow (you'd likely need to do this in c++).

The most annoying challenges with dealing with DIB's are:

1. Converting a DIB to an actual "image" ready for display and
2. Converting an actual "image" into a DIB
3. Saving a DIB as something other than a .BMP

Core references when I started learning the "horror" that images actually are:

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183562(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183562%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162973(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162973%28VS.85%29.aspx)

How you go about getting to/from .NET Image's... well... that's a good question :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine using LockBits/BitmapData, if you are using a 32bpp [P]ARGB pixel format.  The trick is that you will have to copy the data one row at a time so that it aligns in the correct places.  You should be able to do this using something like:

```
Rectangle srcArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, srcBitmap.Width, srcBitmap.Height);
BitmapData srcData = srcBitmap.LockBits(srcArea, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, destBitmap.PixelFormat);
Rectangle destArea = new Rectangle(25, 25, srcBitmap.Width, srcBitmap.Height);
BitmapData destData = destBitmap.LockBits(destArea, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, destBitmap.PixelFormat);

IntPtr srcPtr = srcData.Scan0;
IntPtr destPtr = destData.Scan0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[srcData.Stride];
for (int i = 0; i < srcData.Height; ++i)
{
    Marshal.Copy(srcPtr, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, destPtr, buffer.Length);

    srcPtr += srcData.Stride;
    destPtr += destData.Stride;
}

srcBitmap.UnlockBits(srcData);
destBitmap.UnlockBits(destData);
```

As a warning, this code won't work as is because I am not sure what the right incantations are for incrementing IntPtr's.  I've done this same type of thing before, but in C++.  Also, I don't know if there is a way to directly copy the data instead of using an intermediate buffer.

An additional caveat: the LockBits call srcBitmap and the sizing of the buffer assume that srcBitmap will be completely enclosed in destBitmap.  If this is not the case (some part of the bitmap will be cropped off) the area locked and the size of the buffer will need to be adjusted.

If you are not using a 32bpp pixel format (ie 24bpp), it will be more difficult.  The stride of your source BitmapData may include some amount of padding that should not be copied.  You could work around this by calculating the amount of actual pixel data in a source row, and copy this amount.  Indexed pixel formats would be even more work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [the internal bitmap memory structure.](https://web.archive.org/web/20121203144033/http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm)

The best approach, I think, would be to not try to set the BitmapData directly.  Instead, I would make a single, shared byte array of the appropriate size, and set the byte array directly from your smaller images.

When you compose your larger image, you can take the final byte array and directly [make a Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx) from the byte data.

This has the advantage of allowing you to control the memory management, thread the operations, etc, as you seemed to want to do in your original post.  It should be very fast for the data access, as well.